# Can you use the training parameter with tf.keras.Model() constructor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

Is it possible to get the correct value of the `training` parameter passed to a layer in a model made using the `tf.keras.Model()` constructor (the "functional" API) or do you have to subclass `tf.keras.Model()` to do that?

I need `training` for `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: not really.
[Keras Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer?version=stable) has `trainable` parameter which you can access and modify. But that's more used for freezing weights.

As for `Sequential` API, as for today, the documentation is scarce on how the BatchNorm behaves in inference mode. There are even some opened GitHub Issues [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9522) and [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12400).

`tf.keras.Model()` API gives you more control on the flow and how the layers behave so if you are not concerned about `Saved Model` format I'd stick with that.